# Name already numbered vertices in an undirected graph using R

Tags: r, graph, social-networking, igraph

So I've been able to develop a graph of entities based on text, a sample is below.

```
                                  X1 X2
              PERSON Sherlock Holmes  1
       PERSON Sir Arthur Conan Doyle  1
              PERSON Sherlock Holmes  2
                       PERSON Watson  2
                     PERSON Moriarty  2
```

I've been successful at creating an undirected graph with the relationships between the entities in column X1 and column X2. The numbers in column X2 are group numbers. Sherlock Holmes and Sir Arthur Conan Doyle are in the same group. Ideally I'd like to create and undirected graph not between the entity in column X1 and the group number in Column X2 but the entity and the other members of the group like below.

```
                                  X1 X2
              PERSON Sherlock Holmes  PERSON Sherlock Holmes
              PERSON Sherlock Holmes  PERSON Sir Arthur Conan Doyle
       PERSON Sir Arthur Conan Doyle  PERSON Sir Arthur Conan Doyle
       PERSON Sir Arthur Conan Doyle  PERSON Sherlock Holmes
              PERSON Sherlock Holmes  PERSON Sherlock Holmes
              PERSON Sherlock Holmes  PERSON Watson
              PERSON Sherlock Holmes  PERSON Moriarty
                       PERSON Watson  PERSON Watson
                       PERSON Watson  PERSON Sherlock Holmes
                       PERSON Watson  PERSON Moriarty
                     PERSON Moriarty  PERSON Moriarty
                     PERSON Moriarty  PERSON Sherlock Holmes
                     PERSON Moriarty  PERSON Watson
```

It would also be really nice to be able to remove the duplicates within the graph so that I got the result below.

```
                                  X1 X2
              PERSON Sherlock Holmes  PERSON Sir Arthur Conan Doyle
       PERSON Sir Arthur Conan Doyle  PERSON Sherlock Holmes
              PERSON Sherlock Holmes  PERSON Watson
              PERSON Sherlock Holmes  PERSON Moriarty
                       PERSON Watson  PERSON Sherlock Holmes
                       PERSON Watson  PERSON Moriarty
                     PERSON Moriarty  PERSON Sherlock Holmes
                     PERSON Moriarty  PERSON Watson
```

I used the below code to get the text into the data frame with the group numbers.

```
num.el <- sapply(entities.list, length)
association.matrix <- cbind(unlist(entities.list), rep(1:length(entities.list), num.el))
```

So here is the actual code I get the errors with as requested by Mr. Flick. The data is an enron email.

```
entities.list <-
$all4
[1] " "           "PERSON kaye"

$all9
[1] "MISC Content-Type : text plain; charset=us-ascii" "ORGANIZATION X-From"                           
"PERSON Kaye Ellis"                               
[4] "PERSON Lisa Mackey"                               "MISC X-bcc"
```

Conform list to dataframe

```
association.matrix <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(entities.list), byrow=T))
association.matrix
```

Conform list to a list where entities in same list item are grouped by association in a number

```
num.el <- sapply(entities.list, length)
association.matrix <- cbind(unlist(entities.list), rep(1:length(entities.list), num.el))
```

remove empty string entries

```
 association.matrix <- association.matrix[!apply(association.matrix, 1, function(x)     
 any(x==" ")),]
```

Coerce matrix to dataframe and remove strings as factors
    association.matrix <- data.frame(association.matrix, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

So the data looks like this now

```
                                                X1 X2
1                                      PERSON kaye  1
2 MISC Content-Type : text plain; charset=us-ascii  2
3                              ORGANIZATION X-From  2
4                                PERSON Kaye Ellis  2
5                               PERSON Lisa Mackey  2
6                                       MISC X-bcc  2
```

Here is Mr. Flick's script that I'm trying to get working

```
association.matrix <- do.call(rbind, lapply(tapply(association.matrix$X1,     
association.matrix$X2, combn, 2), function(x) 
  rbind(t(x), t(x)[,2:1])))
```

And here's the error I get.

```
Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : n < m
```

Answer (score 1):

So if your input data is

```
dd<- data.frame(X1 = c("PERSON Sherlock Holmes", "PERSON Sir Arthur Conan Doyle", 
    "PERSON Sherlock Holmes", "PERSON Watson", "PERSON Moriarty"), 
    X2 = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), stringsAsFactors=FALSE
)
```

It seems like you can generate the results you want with

```
mm <- do.call(rbind, lapply(tapply(dd$X1, dd$X2, combn, 2), function(x) 
    rbind(t(x), t(x)[,2:1]))
)
```

which gives

```
     [,1]                            [,2]                           
[1,] "PERSON Sherlock Holmes"        "PERSON Sir Arthur Conan Doyle"
[2,] "PERSON Sir Arthur Conan Doyle" "PERSON Sherlock Holmes"       
[3,] "PERSON Sherlock Holmes"        "PERSON Watson"                
[4,] "PERSON Sherlock Holmes"        "PERSON Moriarty"              
[5,] "PERSON Watson"                 "PERSON Moriarty"              
[6,] "PERSON Watson"                 "PERSON Sherlock Holmes"       
[7,] "PERSON Moriarty"               "PERSON Sherlock Holmes"       
[8,] "PERSON Moriarty"               "PERSON Watson"
```

And you can make that a directed graph with

```
library(igraph)
gg <- graph.edgelist(mm)
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry I haven't answered sooner, can't for the life of me get this working on my actual data. Your example worked perfectly though. Keep getting error    Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : n < m   Any ideas what I could be doing incorrectly? Also when I instead try and coerce the data into a matrix instead of a dataframe I get the following    Error in association.matrix$X2 : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: @Jake Without a reproducible example I can't really help. I have no idea what might be wrong in your real data.